# Solve equation using the quadratic reciprocity law

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to find out if there is a solution to the congruence relation $x^2 \equiv 160 \mod 51$ by using the quadratic reciprocity law. Given that $51$ is not prime, I do not know how to use the results about the quadratic reciprocity law. I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: $a\equiv b\bmod{51}$ iff $a\equiv b\bmod3$ and $a\equiv b\bmod{17}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks. I have a remarque: $a = b  \mod 51 \iff a = b \mod 3$ or $a = b \mod 17$ since both $3$ and $17$ are primes. Given $pq|s,$ where $p,q$ are primes, then $p|s$ or $q|s$. Do you agree ? I am asking this since if one of the congruences fails to hold and the other holds, I am wondering if the initial congruence will have a solution ?

Comment: When $p,q$ are coprime, $pq\mid s$ iff $p\mid s$ *and* $q\mid s.$ Otherly said: the l.c.m. of two coprime integers is their product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x^2-160$ to be divisible by $51$, we need it being divisible by $17$,
so $x^2\equiv 160\mod{17}$ is necessary. However, using reciprocity, the quadratic symbol shows
$$\left(\frac{160}{17}\right)=\left(\frac{7}{17}\right)=\left(\frac{17}{7}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)=-\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)=-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=-1.$$
Therefore, we have no solution for $x$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).